# Play not demuxed H.264 stream on Android?

Tags: android, stream, h.264, raspberry-pi2

I need to make an appliation, that would be able to play H.264 byte stream (from raspberry pi camera module), without any conversion (demux) on the raspberry itself.

Normally, on computer, I am using mplayer and it works great. Like described in [this article](http://zacharybears.com/low-latency-raspberry-pi-video-streaming/)

But I need to make it work in my application on Android smartphone.

There is some mplayer for android, but it is 4 years old!

Any simple solution?